# YouTube API v3 Title Order Possible Bug

Tags: youtube-data-api

When retrieving videos ordered by title I keep getting random order.

I have titled all of my videos in format `yyyy_mm_dd_text_text`.  I would expect for the videos to then be ascending order by date.  However, it is returning the results in some other order that I cannot figure out.  Below is my query with results. I had to replace the 'https' text with 'xxxxx' to post.

REQUEST URL

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=title&part=snippet&channelId=UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw&type=video&maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

RESPONSE

```
200 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
     "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/CYrwvO110znYloTEEulr-DLnwZk\"",
     "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 30,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
     },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
       "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/DfYb30ZT6T0Mybzuv-28cfrhWMc\"",
       "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "cKy8DByLdPw"
       },
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-07-07T00:55:03.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw",
        "title": "2014_06_29_thomas_pope",
        "description": "Thomas Pope~ 06/29/2014~ Matthew 14.",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/cKy8DByLdPw/default.jpg"
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/cKy8DByLdPw/mqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/cKy8DByLdPw/hqdefault.jpg"
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "cbccolumbus",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      },
      {
       "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
       "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/7uZq0_S30z-8CSeGD5jIXBoTxB0\"",
       "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "5X2DVfxNcuM"
       },
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-07-08T23:35:19.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw",
        "title": "2014_07_06_thomas_pope",
        "description": "Thomas Pope~ 07/06/2014~ 2 Samuel 9.",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/5X2DVfxNcuM/default.jpg"
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/5X2DVfxNcuM/mqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/5X2DVfxNcuM/hqdefault.jpg"
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "cbccolumbus",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      },
      {
       "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
       "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/ghNMxJN-RK4dNFDZ6eLn8HsEksk\"",
       "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "62-vb672TQg"
       },
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-01-05T02:00:59.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw",
        "title": "2014_08_10_thomas_pope",
        "description": "Thomas Pope~ 08/10/2014~ \"Slowing down\"~ Matthew 11; Proverbs 21.",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/62-vb672TQg/default.jpg"
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/62-vb672TQg/mqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/62-vb672TQg/hqdefault.jpg"
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "cbccolumbus",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      },
      {
       "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
       "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/t8r_vx5VaCY582n9yNRrs2w1tr4\"",
       "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "fi3p32Kc2lM"
       },
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-06-08T21:30:45.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw",
        "title": "2014_06_08_thomas_pope",
        "description": "Thomas Pope~ 06/08/2014~ Genesis 28.",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/fi3p32Kc2lM/default.jpg"
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/fi3p32Kc2lM/mqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/fi3p32Kc2lM/hqdefault.jpg"
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "cbccolumbus",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      },
      {
       "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
       "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/zkfT5mWgdjRaZrTl3yg2Nf0iApo\"",
       "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "myRXxo37aic"
       },
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-05-19T23:07:14.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCVVBdHej8265d9aXk0f8Kpw",
        "title": "2014_02_23_thomas_pope",
        "description": "Thomas Pope~ 02/23/2014~ 1 Corinthians 10; Genesis 3.",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/myRXxo37aic/default.jpg"
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/myRXxo37aic/mqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "xxxxx://i.ytimg.com/vi/myRXxo37aic/hqdefault.jpg"
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "cbccolumbus",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, strange. Perhaps numbers are being ignored when sorting? But it doesn't make sense, agreed